# Adding User Input To An Array (C)

Tags: c

beginner in C here. Sorry for the lame question. I've writing a program that takes ten integers from the user and then adds them to an array. It works, but for some reason it prompts the user 13 times for an integer, and doesn't include the "Please enter an integer:" part on the second prompt. Otherwise it still creates the array and saves the first ten numbers. I just can't get it to stop asking for integers 13 times.

```
int main () {

    FILE fp*
    int *arr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*10);

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
            printf("Enter an integer:");
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
            printf("arr[%d] = %d: \n", 10-i-1, arr[10-i-1]);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

This is how it currently runs:

> Enter an integer:1
>
> Enter an integer:2
>
> Enter an integer:3
>
> Enter an integer:4
>
> Enter an integer:5
>
> Enter an integer:6
>
> Enter an integer:7
>
> Enter an integer:8
>
> Enter an integer:9
>
> Enter an integer:10
>
> Enter an integer:11
>
> Enter an integer:12
>
> arr[9] = 10:
>
> arr[8] = 9:
>
> arr[7] = 8:
>
> arr[6] = 7:
>
> arr[5] = 6:
>
> arr[4] = 5:
>
> arr[3] = 4:
>
> arr[2] = 3:
>
> arr[1] = 2:
>
> arr[0] = 1:

Comment: If you `malloc` space for 10 integers, then the valid indexes are 0 thru 9. So the `for` loop should be `for (i=0; i < 10; i++)` And if you want to iterate through the array backwards, then it's `for (i=9; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 3):

Off by one errors in your first loop, probably causing a stack corruption:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *arr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * ARRAY_LENGTH);

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter an integer %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = ARRAY_LENGTH-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("arr[%d] = %d: \n", i, arr[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy
Enter an integer 0:1
Enter an integer 1:2
Enter an integer 2:3
Enter an integer 3:4
Enter an integer 4:5
Enter an integer 5:6
Enter an integer 6:7
Enter an integer 7:8
Enter an integer 8:9
Enter an integer 9:10
arr[9] = 10:
arr[8] = 9:
arr[7] = 8:
arr[6] = 7:
arr[5] = 6:
arr[4] = 5:
arr[3] = 4:
arr[2] = 3:
arr[1] = 2:
arr[0] = 1:
```

Comment: You can also make the second loop iterate from reverse `for (int i = ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i >= 0; i--) { printf("arr[%d] = %d:", i, arr[i]); }`

Comment: Dooohhh, you are of course absolutely correct. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something a bit different. It changes the size when you enter the new numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int array[];
}data_t;

data_t *addNumber(data_t **data, int number)
{
    data_t *tmp;
    size_t size = 0;

    if(*data)
    {
        size = (*data) -> size;
    }

    tmp = realloc(*data, (size + 1) * sizeof(int) + sizeof(**data));
    if(tmp)
    {
        *data = tmp;
        (*data) -> size = size + 1;
        (*data) -> array[size] = number;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    data_t *array = NULL;
    char str[500];

    while(fgets(str, 500, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        int number;

        if(sscanf(str, "%d", &number) != 1) break;
        if(!addNumber(&array, number))
        {
            printf("Error adding number\n");
        }
    }
    if(array)
    {
       for(size_t index = 0; index < array -> size; index ++)
       {
           printf("Index %zu Number: %d\n", index, array -> array[index]);
       }
    }
}
```